# Understanding background processes and terminal process group id

Tags: ps, job-control, jobs

I am reading the bash reference manual about Job control found [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_78.html#SEC85) (emphasis mine):

> To facilitate the implementation of the user interface to job control,
> the operating system maintains the notion of a current terminal
> process group ID. **Members of this process group** (processes whose
> process group ID is equal to the current terminal process group ID)
> receive keyboard-generated signals such as SIGINT. These processes **are
> said to be in the foreground. Background processes are those whose
> process group ID differs from the terminal's;**

I am trying to run a little experiment to confirm this, but I am not getting the results I am expecting.

I have two terminals windows running, (my default terminal is `zsh` and I am running `bash` from there, in case this changes anything).

The "experiment" goes as follows:

1. Run a long process in terminal A, I choose `ping -c 4000 google.com`
2. In terminal B, Check the `pgid` of ping running in terminal A, should be the same as terminal A
3. Send suspend character in terminal A, now ping should be suspended and added to jobs in terminal A
4. Check the `pgid` of ping command, it should be different from the terminal A.

To check the process info I am using the following:
`ps -e --forest   -o pid  -o ppid  -o comm  -o pgid | grep -E 'bas|zsh|pin'`

**Actual results**
Before staring ping

```
 287562  287551  |   \_ zsh      287562
 351151  287562  |   |   \_ bas  351151
 354401  287551  |   \_ zsh      354401
 354486  354401  |       \_ bas  354486
```

After staring ping in the foreground:

```
 287562  287551  |   \_ zsh      287562
 351151  287562  |   |   \_ bas  351151
 354401  287551  |   \_ zsh      354401
 354486  354401  |       \_ bas  354486
 359864  354486  |          pin  359864 # shouldn't this be the same as bash above ?
```

After sending the suspend signal:

```
 287562  287551  |   \_ zsh      287562
 351151  287562  |   |   \_ bas  351151
 354401  287551  |   \_ zsh      354401
 354486  354401  |       \_ bas  354486
 359864  354486  |          pin  359864 # shouldn't this change after moving to the background?
```

My questions are:
How come `ping` didn't have the same `pgid` as its parent terminal ?
How come ping `pgid` didn't change when moving from foreground to the background ?

Comment: When ping runs in the foreground, bash waits the background. Since only one process group (aka job, IDed by pgid) can be in foreground, ping and bash could not have the same pgid ;-) When ping is running in the foreground, its pgid *is* the pgid of its terminal. I suggest you add a `-o tpgid` to your `ps` command (notice the **t**: **t**pgid).

Comment: You seem to assume that the foreground process group (job) is fixed and bash moves processes in and out of it when putting them in the fg or bg. That's not how it works: bash tells the kernel which of the jobs is the foreground one with ioctl(TIOCSPGRP), and then all the other jobs become background jobs.

Comment: See also, if you are on Linux, "Process group ID and session ID" in [`man 7 credentials`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) for an alternative summary of shell job control concepts.

Comment: @user414777: Thanks, that did clear it up partially. I was mixing `pgid` and `tpgid`. However, when I redo the steps, `ping` has the same `tpgid` when in background and foreground. The behavior I am trying to observe is is the change in `tpgid` when the jobs move to background/foreground. I am not seeing the following "`Background processes are those whose process group ID differs from the terminal's`", unless I am misunderstanding what it is trying to say

Comment: It does not for me. When ping is in background "its" `tpgid` (actually the tpgid of its controlling tty) would be different from its `pgid`. Try with just `ps  -o pgid,tpgid <pid-of-ping>`, maybe you can't see the tree from all that `--forest` ;-). And update your question.